# How to output results when Inheritance used in Entity Framework (Discriminator)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 4 classes that drive from a base class.

The sub classes has some extra properties. And this results in a single combined table in the database with an extra column 'Discriminator'. This is done automatically by EF to identify the type of the object when the data is loaded back.

**BaseTask** is the base class

```
Task1 
Task2
Task3
Task4
```

Task1 class has a property called  **SpecialKey**.
the classes drives from BaseTask

So now I would like to list all the objects from table to a UI.

When I load the table results as below:

```
var tasks = DbContext.BaseTasks.ToList();

foreach(var task in tasks){

// output all columns details from BaseTask table from database
}
```

But as you can see that because **SpecialKey** is not part of the base class I cannot output that property.

How can I overcome this problem?

Do I really have to do the following?

```
    var tasks = DbContext.BaseTasks.ToList();

        foreach(var task in tasks.OfType<Task1>){
        // output task 1 details
        }

        foreach(var task in tasks.OfType<Task2>){
        // output task 2 details
        }

        foreach(var task in tasks.OfType<Task3>){
        // output task 3 details
        }
```

etc...
This looks really messy. This really tells me that inheritance was not a good idea to create table objects.

Comment: There is nothing EF specific. Output base properties. Then use `as`, `is` / `cast` to output the derived class properties.

Comment: Do all classes that derive from `BaseTask` have a "Special Key"?

Comment: You would be correct, at least as far as the property called `SpecialKey` is concerned. Using a base class in your scenario would be more appropriate to implement an interface such has `ISpecialKey` or similar

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple check to see what type it is and do something specific:

```
foreach(var task in tasks){

    if (task is Task1) { // do whatever you need to... }
    // other checks...
}
```

Comment: This seems the way to go. But I use AutoMapper to map BaseTask to TaskViewModel. There things get complicated. As the BaseTask is also a property of another object. I use eager loading to load the object properties. I should share all the code to make a sense of it anyway. Thanks